# High speed ethernet messages without congestion

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, udp

I have two programs that transmits UDP messages between them. The first program is a simulator and the other program is a controller.

Both simulator and controller is written i C++. I want the simulator to transmit the simulation state to the controller that in turn sends a control signal to the simulator. All messages will be under 1kb.

I have now used UDP for the ethernet connection. The speed is good for the first 2-3 seconds, and then it drops significantly to 1/10th of the original speed. I suspect this is due to network congestion.

The problem:
I though that UDP was faster than TCP, but do you think that TCP will be faster due to the congestion? Is there anything I can do to increase the speed?

**EDIT: How I measure the speed**

I have just done some simulation with varying length

- Simulating 5 seconds: 1.10s
- Simulating 50 seconds: 26s
- Simulating 100 seconds: 61s

You can see that the speed drops when the simulation is run for longer period.

**EDIT2: blocking/non-blocking**

I am using non-blocking sending and blocking receiving. The simulation is written using Simulink, and receive and send is implemented as two C++-blocks.
My guess is that the sending happens first, and then the receive-block is run.
There are no fixed intervals. The sending happens when the calculations are finished. It's all in one thread.

Comment: Please define how you are measuring your speed.  UDP has no natural rate limiting other than dropped packets.  Perhaps you are filling up intermediate buffers initially, and then dropping packets because you've saturated the buffers.

Comment: Some questions:   Are you using blocking or non-blocking I/O?  Are you calling send() at fixed intervals, or are you calling send() only when the socket selects/polls as ready-for-write?  Are you doing your network I/O in a dedicated thread, or does the same thread also do other non-trivial tasks that might sometimes prevent it from calling send() (or recv()) in a timely manner?